# Conditional check on files with specific file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

Greetings fellow mortals! I will cut right through it.

#### What I am trying to achieve & how it works

---

I am currently trying to create a simple batch-script which **iterates** through files in a source directory, **validates** the file extension and **count** the file size of each file with the ***right*** extension, which in this case is `.xml`.

Upon checking for these conditions, the files will be moved to their respective directory.

#### What I've tried so far

---

While doing the first condition of checking the file extension, my logic seems to be flawed. (*explained after the code block.*)
I am not used to creating scripts in `batch` and therefore not entirely used to the syntax - but I hope it's correct!

I've kept the `echo`'s as a debug reference for the output later in this post.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\lorem\ipsum"
SET "destdir=C:\foo\bar"

FOR %%G IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO (
    IF NOT "%%~nxG"=="*.xml" (
        echo %%~nxG
        ::echo (MOVE "%%G" "%destdir%\not-accepted")
        echo "move file to \not-accepted"
    ) ELSE (
        FOR %%i in ("%sourcedir%\*.xml") DO (
            @set count=%%~zi
            echo "%count%"
            IF "%count%" LEQ 200 (
                echo "move file to \empty-pba"
            ) ELSE (
                echo "move file to \import"
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
```

The first statement never seem to give a **false** condition, despite having file extensions that doesn't match the condition and therefore does not continue to the next **for-loop**, meaning the allowed file extension is always moved to the **\not-accepted** folder.

**The output is as follows:**

```
lorem.xml
"move to \not-accepted"
foo.pdf
"move to \not-accepted"
ipsum.xml
"move to \not-accepted"
bar.pdf
"move to \not-accepted"
```

#### My initial question

---

Is my logic flawed here? My first bet is that I've probably messed up the `if`-statement somehow, either syntax error or that I've completely missed on the logic here. Am I doing something illegal?

---

The time you've already spent reading this and the help is already greatly appreciated! <3

Comment: `*` does not belong in the statement `IF NOT "%%~nxG"=="*.xml"`

Comment: @T3RR0R Thank you! I did not take into consideration that `if` statements does not accept pattern matching. Would the better approach be to use `/f delims=` to get the extension and store the extension as a variable to be used in the statement?

Comment: drop the `n`  and just use the `x` extension modifier: `IF NOT "%%~xG"==".xml"`

Comment: Embarassing. I should have double-checked the modifiers, my bad. Thank you so much for the help, this solved my issue. You may leave an answer for some additional internet points if you'd like. :)

Comment: I would also add the `/i` switch to make the `if` statement case insensitive, just incase someone decided to give the extension `.XML` instead of `.xml` so do `if /i not "%%~xG" == ".xml"` You are welcome to test it from `cmd` as `if not ".XML" == ".xml" echo not xml` vs `if /i not ".XML" == ".xml" echo not xml`

Comment: @Gerhard Clever suggestion, didn't think about that *case*. (pun intended)
Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question statement suggested you were wanting to count the number of characters in each file, but your code is providing only the file size. That would only work if your XML files use only single byte ASCII characters, and no BOM, but XML uses Unicode, usually UTF-8, can include a BOM, and may therefore use from 2, to 4 bytes per character, for those over U+007F, _(2 bytes for U+0080..U+07FF, 3 bytes for U+0800..U+FFFF, and 4 bytes for U+10000..U+10FFFF)_. Could you please explain, whether you really want a character count? or just a file size?

Comment: @Compo Nice observation! You're right. When I started on this earlier today I initially wanted to count the **characters** of the file - but changed this to the **file size** (more convenient for my case) after I wrote the introduction to the question. I've edited the question to reflect the code provided. Thanks for new information about the charset XML uses, did not know this.

Comment: Also your `count` variable needs [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

Comment: I am confused as to why you have nested `FOR` commands?  The `FOR` and `IF..ELSE` commands are all you need.  And because you have nested `FOR` commands, you are iterating the entire source FOLDER multiple times which is super inefficient for large folder structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am not fully understanding what you are trying to accomplish but it seems like your code is doing way more than it has to. You should not need the nested `FOR` commands to accomplish this task. You are already iterating the folder so there is no need to do it again.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\lorem\ipsum"
SET "destdir=C:\foo\bar"

FOR %%G IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO (
    IF /I NOT "%%~xG"==".xml" (
        echo %%~xG
        REM echo (MOVE "%%G" "%destdir%\not-accepted")
        echo "move file to \not-accepted"
    ) ELSE (
        echo File SIZE %%~zG"
        IF %%~zG LEQ 200 (
            echo "move file to \empty-pba"
        ) ELSE (
            echo "move file to \import"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Yup! I noticed I iterated the same folder twice, got it fixed right after @Gerhard corrected my modifier. This would be the working solution indeed. Forgot to edit my question.